# How can we read JSON data from URL, convert to dataframe, and save as CSV

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, url

I'm playing around with some code to read JSON encoded data from a URL, push it into a data frame and save the results to a CSV. The code that I attempted to run is shown below. I think this is pretty close, but something is wrong, because nothing gets downloaded.

```
import urllib
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

all_links = ['https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/474131755_abrazomaranahospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=9a27928_2',
 'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621861138_abrazocavecreekhospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=674fd6f_2',
 'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621809851_abrazomesahospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=13953222_2',
 'https://www.baptisthealthsystem.com/docs/global/standard-charges/621811285_abrazosurprisehospital_standardcharges.json?sfvrsn=c8113dcf_2']
for item in all_links:
    #print(item)
    try:
        length = len(item)
        first_under = item.find('_') + 1
        last_under = item.rfind('?') - 21
        file_name = item[first_under:last_under]
        print(file_name)
        # store the response of URL
        response = urlopen(item)
        data = json.loads(response.read())
        #print(type(data))
        data = json.loads(item.read().decode())
        df = pd.DataFrame(json_normalize(data, 'metrics'), encoding='mac_roman')
        DOWNLOAD_PATH = 'C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\hospital_data\\' + file_name + '.csv'
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(df,DOWNLOAD_PATH)
    except Exception as e: print(e)
```

Any thoughts on what could be wrong here?

Comment: You are catching all exceptions and printing them. Are any errors being thown? Is the problem with downloading or saving? Does you line `print(type(data))` show that the data is downloaded?

Comment: Also, this line looks suspect `data = json.loads(item.read().decode())` should it be `response.read().decode()`?

Comment: Oh, duh, I forgot to post the error message. Here is the error message that I'm seeing: 
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 1055: invalid start byte

Comment: Its hard to know what is going wrong without knowing where it is going wrong in your block of code. Can you remove the `try` block and tell us exactly where the error is?